# Persist Parse User between AppStore Updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I was under the impression that [PFUser currentUser] handled caching the user between AppStore updates but I guess I'm wrong.

Put another way: I don't want the user to have to login every time I push an update to the App Store. Is there a Parse function to handle this? Or do I use NSUserDefaults or something?

First for me on this subject... Be kind :)

Comment: Wow, can you cite a source? I also thought that a PFUser would remain logged-in after an app update.

Comment: Source is my own app that's had 5 new versions in 2 months and it has made me login every time the app updates.

Comment: I do not see this behavior on my app, when updating through HockeyApp - which I assume is the same as the App Store update. What does your 'didFinishLaunching' code look like?

Comment: if ([PFUser currentUser]) { showMainView } else {showLogin/SignupView}

Comment: Yeah its fine going to test flight its once it hits the app store

Comment: I guess I have no definitive information, then; I can't say for sure, but I was fairly sure that logins were persisting for my app. I have an update waiting for review, so I can check back with details in a few weeks.

Comment: My app update just got approved. I can confirm that my app stays logged in through app store updates. I suspect that fetching the user is your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the current user first - perhaps the Parse singleton doesn't store/persist currentUser. My code looks like this:

```
 //[[PFUser currentuser] fetch] sometimes hangs for a while, I don't know why. Kick off to the bg.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[PFUser currentUser] fetch];

        if (![PFUser currentUser])
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Display login screen
                [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:authViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
            });
        }
    });
```